# reactjs Twilio video chat - appending video as remote media

Tags: reactjs, video, twilio

I am new to reactjs and working on a twilio video chat based component. Its been proposed that when someone joins the call, this person's video is attached to remote-media?

I've found some links referring to building a react powered Twilio video chat.

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/03/building-a-react-powered-video-chat.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. How can we help?

Comment: I am asking - is there a need or a method for attaching a person's video as remote media?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When a [participant](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/Participant.html) joins a video room you and you want to see their video and hear their audio, then you need to connect their [incoming media tracks](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/Track.html) to a video element in your application. You can listen to the participant's `trackAdded` and `trackRemoved` events so that you know when you attach and detach the tracks. For example:

```
room.on('participantConnected', function(participant) {
  participant.on('trackAdded', function(track) {
    // Attach the track to a DOM element that you have access to.
    // This creates a <video> element for VideoTracks and an <audio> element for AudioTracks
    track.attach(element);
  });

  participant.on('trackRemoved', function(track) {
    track.detach();
  })
}
```

I am pretty new to React myself, but I think the way that Eddie attached the media in his blog post, using a `ref` in the JSX and then `this.refs.localMedia` in the component lifecycle event to get the reference to the element and attach the media, is a good approach.

Note, that blog post uses the deprecated Conversations API for Video, rather than the new Rooms API. However the participant/tracks model and attaching tracks to the DOM is similar.

Let me know if this helps at all.